# Alternative ways for changing paths when using MSBuild

Tags: c#, msbuild

I want to build my solution file using MSBuild but there is one issue. My MSBuild file is located at `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\`. So now only if I have my entire solution and projects files in this path am I able to compile the solution. But I cant keep having all my solution and project files in `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\`. The location of my solution files maybe at any location in my pc or in TFS, and I'll have to use MSBuild to compile it.

I saw in some forum that I'll have to change the path in regedit in the location 
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\3.5`, but then it still remains static. If I want to execute a solution file which is in TFS then I'll have to again change the path in regedit.

Is there any alternative to this?

Comment: How are actually building your solutions when using MSBuild?

Comment: do you mean to ask "who are actually building your solutions when using MSbuild?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The msbuild.exe is there on my system, too. That is perfectly fine, as it's the task of VS or build tools to handle that. Normally you would either run a build script with `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\` in the path environment, or your build solution knows where to find it. Usually, the msbuild.exe has to be changed only when you retarget to a different framework version (say 4.0). For building on a clean machine, the prerequisites should be set up correctly. So there should be no need to include msbuild.exe in your repository. Probably this would be considered *bad practice*. Do you have any reason, why you want to have the msbuild.exe versioned?

Comment: I set the environment variable to C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\ and now it is working. Thanks.